# Automatic Next-translate i18

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, react-i18next

I want to do internalisation in my nextJs project with i18 and next-translate.
It  works great on my local machine, perhaps when I deploy it it doesn't react correctly.
Indeed in my local machine, it translates automatically when I go to localhost:3000, it redirects automaticly to localhost:3000/fr, but when I deploy it, it doesn't, it stays [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) . On the website deployed I have a langage selector to test, when I click on FR it translates correctly. I don't understand why it doesn't automaticly like when I'm in local machine

When I use :

```
const { locale, defaultLocale } = useRouter();
```

on my local machine I have locale = fr (my langage in my explorer is set to french), but on the net it stays en-US

In my code I structured my translation with these methods :

-next.config.js

```
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

module.exports = nextTranslate({
  webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
    return config;
  },
  i18n: {
    localeDetection: true,
  },
})
```

-i18n.json

```
{
  "locales": ["en-US", "fr"],
  "defaultLocale": "en-US",
  "pages": {
    "/": ["index"],
    "/services": ["services"],
    "/projects": ["projects"],
    "/project-dormeuil": ["dormeuil"],
    "/theme": ["theme"],
    "*": ["layout"]
  }
}
```

I have this hook to keep my translation during the transitions

```
export default function useTranslationMe(namespace, options) {
    const { t, lang } = useTranslation(namespace, options);
    const T = useMemo(() => t, [lang]);
    return { t: T, lang };
}
```

- In my index file for example I translate my text like so :

```
    let {t, lang} = useTranslationMe('index');
    return (
    {t('intro-skills-index')}
     )
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're seeing the expected `Accept-Language` header (`fr`) when accessing your production website?

Comment: @juliomalves in my accept langage I see : fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar-FR;q=0.6,ar;q=0.5

Comment: If it can help, I tried on incognito page with google and it WORKS, but on other mobiles of my family same result nothing, other computers same result nothing, others incognito of different browsers nothing also ... In my side I removed all the cache, extensions etc ...

Comment: Does your app set the [`NEXT_LOCALE` cookie](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#leveraging-the-next_locale-cookie) by any chance? That could be overwriting the locale from the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: @juliomalves, no my app doesnt set NEXT_LOCALE cookie.